# JPA empty object

Tags: java, jpa

I have this Java Object which I want to use to display data from DB.

```
public TData td;

    public class TData {

        private long id;
        private String key;
        private String language;
        private String translation;

        public TData() {
        };

        public TData(long id, String key, String language, String translation) {
            // super();
            this.id = id;
            this.key = key;
            this.language = language;
            this.translation = translation;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public String getLanguage() {
            return language;
        }

        public void setLanguage(String language) {
            this.language = language;
        }

        public String getTranslation() {
            return translation;
        }

        public void setTranslation(String translation) {
            this.translation = translation;
        }

    }

    public TData getDataObj() {
        return td;
    }
```

This is the DB table which I want to use to get the data:

```
CREATE TABLE translations (
id  SERIAL NOT NULL, 
KEY VARCHAR(255), 
LANGUAGE VARCHAR(255), 
TRANSLATION VARCHAR(255)
)
```

I have a custom JPA object which is used to make queries:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void loadData() {

        td = new TData();

        String query = "SELECT c FROM Translations c WHERE c.Id = '70'";
        //String query = "SELECT p from translations p where id=70";
        td = (TData) dao.jpqlQuerySingle(query);

    }
```

When I open the JSF page the Java object is empty. The Java method `jpqlQuerySingle` is used to return the result as Object but for some reason I get empty Object. Can you help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a String to an Long. This gives you zero results. Try this instead:

```
SELECT c FROM Translations c WHERE c.Id = 70
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tamplar's answer (comparing a long to a String) : you should probably use an object wrapper around you `@Id`, i.e. a `Long` object instead of a `long` primitive data type.

The reason for this : In short, `long` cannot be `null`, and the most common and easy way to check if a persistent object is saved/detached or new is to check whether the `@Id` is `null`.